# $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$ with $A,B\subset V$ vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that, given $V$ and $W$ vector spaces, $A,B\subset V$ vector subspaces and a linear function $f:V\rightarrow W$, $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$?

Comment: If $\;A,B\;$ subspaces, then the definition domain of $\;f\;$ definitely cannot be $\;V\;$, so what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio $f(S)=\{ f(x) |x \in S \}$ is a standard definition in many areas of math ;)

Comment: Perhaps that's the meaning, @N.S....

Answer (score 2):

$f(A + B) = \{ f(a + b) : a \in A, b \in B \} = \{f(a) + f(b)\} = f(A) + f(B)$.  This is all doable since a vector space is a commutative group under $+$, which implies that you can indeed write $A + B = \{a + b : a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Answer (score 1):

i think so..

if $\omega \in A + B$ then $\omega$ is a linear combination of a basis of $A$ + a linear combination of a basis ob $B$. with $f$, you find a linear combination of  the image of the basis of $A$ + a linear combination of the image of the basis of $B$.

The image of a basis it is not a basis, in the general case, but sure generates the whole subspace

then yes, $f(A+B) = f(A) + f(B)$